# C Programming Language, Pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I Stored **"Hello"** world in Character array and assigned the characteres into  char pointer,

```
char a[100],*p;
p=a;
```

I found the length of the string using pointer then  how should i find the **position of the string.**
program

```
char a[100],*p;
int lenth;
printf("Enter the string:");
gets(a);
p=a;

while(*p)
{
    length++;
    p++
}
printf("Length=%d",length);
```

Comment: Define "position of the string" assuming that you want something other that "it starts at a[0] and ends at a[length] (including the nul terminator)".

Comment: you have `p = aa;` .. is that correct?

Comment: what do you mean by position of the string ?

Comment: Never use `gets`. It's impossible to prevent buffer overrun.

Comment: Please explain what is the problem a bit more.

Comment: Make sure you've stored the "Hello World\0" in the char array or will never work.

Comment: make sure you initialize length before you use it, eg `length = 0;`

Comment: `p=a` is working properly i got the output, now i need to find the position of particular character from the given string.

Answer (score 1):

i think if you want to get the length of the string you only need to use strlen(a) to get the length.

but if you want to mimic strlen you could write something like this

```
size_t length = 0;
for (char* p = a; p < a + sizeof(a) && *p; ++p, ++length );
```

Comment: I got the length of the string,  now i need to find the position of the particular character form the given string

Comment: without using **strlen()** function

Answer (score 0):

do a search, p stores the result address, so p - a is the index.

```
char target = 'e';
for (p = a; *p && *p != target; ++p) {};
int result = p - a;
// if target doesn't exists result === Length
```